# Vertical list submenu positioning issues

Tags: css, list

I have a vertical list of images and upon hover it displays a sub menu of 3-5 more images that are links to other pages. All is well there works fine;however, if I scroll any where away from the top of the page and go to hover over the list items then the sub menu list items are not directly parallel to the main list like the should when I do not scroll and initially hover over the list the sub menu displays properly directly next to the parent item in the list. This is just a css list.

I have two images of the good view and the bad view *once I'm scrolled down*.

Any ideas? Thank you!

*Working screenshot, page not scrolled*

[image]

*Not working screenshot, page scrolled*

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><img src="graphics/nav_main_data_files.jpg" alt="">
     <ul class="nested">
         <li><a href="datauploaddatafiles.aspx"><img src="graphics/nav_sub_upload_data_file.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="datarequestsamples.aspx"><img src="graphics/nav_sub_request_samples.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="dataapprovesamples.aspx"><img src="graphics/nav_sub_approve_samples_data.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
     </ul>
         <li><img src="graphics/nav_main_job_tracking.jpg" alt="">
     <ul class="nested">
         <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="graphics/nav_sub_schedule_job.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="graphics/nav_sub_view_job_status.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="graphics/nav_sub_review_prod_totals.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #navcontainer ul { list-style-type: none; }

.nested
 {
     display: none;
     list-style: none;
}
li:hover > .nested
 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: .5em;

}​
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/JVKLw/3/

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Add the code to http://jsfiddle.net and include the CSS. It makes it all so much easier to see the problem and fixing it (if possible).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/squinny/JVKLw/

Comment: sorry, theres the link thanks for helping btw:)

Comment: You said you had some images that show you whats a good view and a bad view. Can you make them available too?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hR7MS.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkq7Y.png

Comment: the first one is the good image the second one is the bad image. they r suppose to be aligned next to data files

Comment: So what is wrong with the behavior that is shown in your fiddle that I've updated it with a dummy image, see http://jsfiddle.net/JVKLw/1/? The submenus align to their parent images.

Comment: correct, it does now my master page which this list is on scrolls vertically due to the size of the page. now if i hover over the images with the page loaded without scrolling it works fine.... as soon as i scroll down at all on the page and then hover the images, it throws the alignment off as seen in the image on my previous comment...idk if that makes any sense

Comment: Allright, the issue is when the page is scrolled down. I updated the fiddle again so it scrolls in the test, http://jsfiddle.net/JVKLw/3/.

Comment: ok now scroll down just a little bit then hover over a image, the sub menu is not aligned as it should be. now scroll back to the top and hover over a list image and those are properly aligned....sorry for the stupidity, i got thrown into this assignment lol css is still new to me

Comment: yes, the fiddle is acting the same as my webpage... try scrolling, then select a list item...it doesnt line next to it like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative and absolute positioning instead of the fixed (which is where the problem lies).

*Example*

**HTML**

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
     <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="datauploaddatafiles.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="datarequestsamples.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="dataapprovesamples.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt="">
      <ul class="nested">
           <li><a href="jobtrackingschedule.aspx"> <img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsviewstatus.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
           <li><a href="jobtrackingsreviewproductiontotals.aspx"><img src="http://www.incrementp.co.jp/ml/en/common/image/menu01_on.gif" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
 #navcontainer ul { list-style-type: none; }

.nested
 {
     display: none;
     list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    position: relative;
}
li:hover > .nested
 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 210px;
    top: 0;
}​
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i greatly appreciate it...you helped alot!!